# powershell webscrape into columns

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

Im attempting to scrape a website.
When testing I can get the values I'm looking for by doing...

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.livesquawk.com/latest-news

($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') | Where { $_.ClassName -match 'latest_news_each_title'}).InnerText
($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') | Where { $_.ClassName -match 'latest_news_each_time'}).InnerText
```

But when I try to put it into a two column return, I get errors and multiple lines of same data?
What am I doing wrong? I'm out of ideas.  Thanks in advance.

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.livesquawk.com/latest-news
$lists = $WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div')
$nodes = $lists[0].childNodes
$r = $lists | % {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Time = $_.getElementsByClassName('latest_news_each_time')[0].innerText.Substring(0) | Where-Object { $_ -match "\d+.*" } | foreach { $Matches.Values }
        

        News = $_.getElementsByClassName('latest_news_each_title')[0].innerText
    }
}

$R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they aren't really grouped together and you already have the logic to get each, you could two arrays and a simple for loop to build the objects.

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.livesquawk.com/latest-news

$title = ($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') | Where { $_.ClassName -match 'latest_news_each_title'}).InnerText
$time = ($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') | Where { $_.ClassName -match 'latest_news_each_time'}).InnerText

for($i = 0; $i -le $title.count; $i++)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Time = $time[$i]
        News = $title[$i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as expected.  Thanks Doug for helping to clear this up for me.

Comment: Would you be able to help me get the href link of each news event? Ive never been able to simply get those as there is no class associated with the href link of each news event?

Comment: I can get links for the whole page but not specific to each news event